# Cassandra: Cannot truncate table

Tags: cassandra, cassandra-2.0, cqlsh

I have a table named buddyme.chatarch.

When trying to truncate the table.

```
cqlsh:buddyme> TRUNCATE chatarch;
```

I am getting this error.

```
TruncateError: <ErrorMessage code=1003 [Error during truncate] message="Error during truncate: Cannot achieve consistency level ALL">
```

What can be the possible reason?
I am new to Cassandra.

Thanks

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21457800/cassandra-truncating-a-table-twice-throws-consistency-exception - might help

Comment: Its not the disk space problem. I have checked this question before.

Comment: Do you have multiple nodes, some of which are presently unavailable?

Comment: Yes. I figured it out. One of the cluster nodes was down, that's why consistency error. Thanks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Even I was facing the same issue. One of the nodes in my cluster was down. Fixed the issue by starting all nodes.

Answer (score 2):

Even though All the 3 nodes in the cluster are up but still facing same issue. It was resolved after following as  below

A TRUNCATE statement results in the immediate, irreversible removal of all data in the named table.
Note: The consistency level must be set to ALL prior to performing a TRUNCATE operation. All replicas must remove the data.

Examples

Set the consistency level to ALL first. TRUNCATE or TRUNCATE TABLE can be used to remove all data from a named table.
CONSISENTENCY ALL;
TRUNCATE user_activity;

CONSISTENCY ALL;
TRUNCATE TABLE menu_item;

Follow the link: https://docs.datastax.com/en/cql/3.1/cql/cql_reference/truncate_r.html